# Is there a way to expand polynomials using Sympy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, sympy

Looking at the Sympy documentation, there seems to be an "expand" function which can be called upon to expand polynomial expressions; however, in practice, this is not working for me. I started off using imaginary numbers:

```
import sympy
sympy.expand((x - 1)(x + i)(x - i))
```

Hoping for "x^3 - x^2 + x - 1", however, instead, this returned the following error: module 'sympy' has no attribute 'expand'

I then changed the expression I wanted to be expanded, as this had caused me to assume that Sympy could not handle complex numbers, to what can be seen below:

```
import sympy
sympy.expand((x - 1)(x - 1)(x + 1))
```

Yet this returned the same error.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: did you create file with name `sympy.py` ? If you have file own file `sympy.py` then `import sympy` will load your file instead of module `sympy` and then it may not find `expand` in your file.

Comment: BW: you have to use `*` in `(x - 1)*(x - 1)*(x + 1)` and you have to create symbols `x = sympy.Symbol('x')` and `i = sympy.Symbol('i')`

Answer (score 1):

I don't have problem to run

```
import sympy

x = sympy.Symbol('x')
i = sympy.Symbol('i')

sympy.expand( (x - 1)*(x + i)*(x - i) )
```

and this gives me

```
-i**2*x + i**2 + x**3 - x**2
```

The only idea: you created file with name `sympy.py` and now `import sympy` loads your file instead of module `sympy` and it can't find `expand` in your file. You have to rename your file `sympy.py` to something different (which is not name of other module).

But you didn't add full error message in question so I can't confirm it.

Answer (score 0):

The imaginary `i` is represented by the capital `I` in sympy. To have a multiplication, an `*` needs to be used explicitly. Also, in Python `^` is strictly reserved for a boolean (or bitwise) exclusive or. Power is represented as `**`.

```py
from sympy import symbols, I, expand

x = symbols('x') 
print(expand((x - 1)*(x + I)*(x - I)))
```

Output: `x**3 - x**2 + x - 1`

Note that an alternative way to call `expand()` is as `expression.expand()` (or `((x - 1)*(x + I)*(x - I)).expand()` as in the example). Often this is a handy way to concatenate several operations.